# What layers are produced by SAGA Potential Incoming Solar Radiation?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, saga, solar-radiation

I estimated the `Potential Incoming Solar Radiation` in `SAGA`. The tool creates a file "direct insolation" and "diffuse insolation". When I export these files as `.tif`, a layerstack of 3 raster layers is produced for each insolation file.

In the documentation of the tool I can not find an advice, what the layers in particular mean. Does anyone knows how to interpret those layers?

Here is a screenshot of the layers from direct insolation
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

beginners fail. I exported the file via "save as image", so off course it creates an RGB-image. In order to provide the original .tif file produced by saga you have to call the tool `export GeoTIFF` (`IMPORT/EXPORT` --> `RGDAL/OGR`) and a single layer .tif will be exported as expected.